# Can't validate form and refreshes page when I hit submit button django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm new to Django and learning some new things and I have a problem that I can't able to validate the contact form and page refreshes when I hit submit button. Can u please go through this code.

I cant able to validate contact form and I can able to validate and store values of join form but the contact form and everything are fine but I don't know where is the problem.

I'm using atom editor for Django

Here is forms.py

```
#forms.py

from django import forms
from django.core import validators
from index.models import *

class Contactform(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Contact_Us
        exclude = ('date',)

    confirm_email = forms.EmailField()
    botcatcher = forms.CharField(required=False,
                                    widget=forms.HiddenInput,
                                    validators=[validators.MaxLengthValidator(0)])

    def clean(self):
        super(Contactform, self).clean()
        name = self.cleaned_data['fullname']
        if len(str(name)) < 4:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Name should contain more than $ letters")


class Joinusform(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Join_Us
        fields = '__all__'

    confirm_email = forms.EmailField()
    botcatcher = forms.CharField(required=False,
                                    widget=forms.HiddenInput,
                                    validators=[validators.MaxLengthValidator(0)])


    def clean(self):
        super(Joinusform, self).clean()
        all_clean_data = self.cleaned_data
        email = all_clean_data['email']
        cemail = all_clean_data['confirm_email']
        phone = all_clean_data['phone']
        registration = all_clean_data['registration']
        experience = all_clean_data['experience']
        hiringreason = all_clean_data['hiringreason']
        role = all_clean_data['role']
        year = all_clean_data['year']
        if email != cemail:
            raise forms.ValidationError("MAKE SURE EMAIL MATCH!!!")

        if len(str(phone)) < 10:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Phone Number should be 10 digits!!!")

        if len(str(registration)) != 8:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Enter your correct Registration No!!!")

        if len(str(experience)) < 10:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Some Required Field is Empty and it should be filled Corectly without any Fake Information!!!")

        if len(str(hiringreason)) < 10:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Some Required Field is Empty and it should be filled Corectly without any Fake Information!!!")

        if role == 'select':
            raise forms.ValidationError("Select Your Role!!!")

        if year == 'select':
            raise forms.ValidationError("Select Which Year are you studying!!!")
```

Here is views.py

```
#views.py

from index import forms as formlocal

def contact(request):

    contact_form = formlocal.Contactform()
    context = {'form':contact_form}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        contact_form = formlocal.Contactform(request.POST)

        if contact_form.is_valid():
            contact_form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect('/')
    return render(request,'index/contact.html',context=context)


 def joinus(request):

    form = formlocal.Joinusform()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = formlocal.Joinusform(request.POST)
        some_var = request.POST.getlist('role')
        if some_var[0] != 'select':

            if form.is_valid():
                form.save(commit=True)
                return redirect('/')
    return render(request,'index/joincoc.html',{'form':form})
```

Here is models.py

```
#models.py


from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import URLValidator
from django.core.validators import MinLengthValidator
from django.utils.timezone import now
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.files.images import get_image_dimensions


class Contact_Us(models.Model):


    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=30,
                               default='',
                               validators=[MinLengthValidator(4)])
    email = models.EmailField()
    message = models.CharField(max_length=250,
                               default='',
                               blank=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=now, blank=True)



    def __str__(self):
        return '{} contacting '.format(self.fullname).capitalize()


class Join_Us(models.Model):

    year_choices = [
        ('1st Year', '1st Year'),
        ('2nd Year', '2nd Year'),
        ('3rd Year', '3rd Year'),
        ('4th Year', '4th Year'),
    ]

    role_choices = [
        ('Content Writer', 'Content Writer'),
        ('Content Provider', 'Content Provider'),
        ('Marketing Manager', 'Marketing Manager'),
        ('Photo/Video Editor', 'Photo/Video Editor'),
        ('Not Mentioned', 'Not Mentioned'),
    ]

    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=30,
                               default='',
                               validators=[MinLengthValidator(4)])
    email = models.EmailField()
    registration = models.IntegerField()
    phone = models.IntegerField()
    experience = models.CharField(max_length=250,
                               default='',
                               validators=[MinLengthValidator(10)])
    hiringreason = models.CharField(max_length=250,
                               default='',
                               validators=[MinLengthValidator(10)])
    year = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        choices=year_choices,
    )
    role = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        choices=role_choices,
    )
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=now, blank=True)



    def __str__(self):
        return 'Name : {}'.format(self.fullname).capitalize()
```

here is contact.html

```
{% include 'Utility/Title.html' %}
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="codeforcoder is a ultimate website for cse students. you can get codes,ppt,ebooks,question papers,placement question and much more.">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,900" rel="stylesheet">

    {% include 'Utility/CSS_Links.html' %}
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
      {% include 'Utility/NavBar.html' %}



      <!-- Main Body Start -->
       <div class="row">

      <form method="POST" class="col xl6 offset-xl3 l6 offset-l3 m12 s12 center ">

        <h3 class="center" style="font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;">Contact US</h3>
            <!-- Modal Trigger -->
    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger center" href="#modal1">Our Contacts</a>

    <!-- Modal Structure -->
    <div id="modal1" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>Phone No : </h4>
        <p>+91 8847240883, +91 8463048477</p>
        <h4>Mail : </h4>
        <p>reply.codeforcoder@gmail.com</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Close</a>
      </div>
    </div>

            <!-- Modal End-->
                        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
              {{ form.errors }}
         <div class="row center">
          <div class="input-field col xl12 l12  m12 s12 center">
            {{ form.fullname }}
            <label>Full Name :</label>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row center">
          <div class="input-field  col xl6 l6 m6 s12 center">
            {{ form.email }}
            <label>Email :</label>
          </div>

          <div class="input-field  col xl6 l6 m6 s12 center">
             {{ form.confirm_email }}
                <label>Confirm Email :</label>
          </div>

       </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col xl12 l12 m12 s12 center">
            {{ form.message }}
            <label for="HiringReason">Message*</label>
          </div>
        </div>
                <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col xl12 l12 m12 s12 center">
            {{ form.botcatcher }}
          </div>
        </div>
        {% csrf_token %}
       <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="submit">Send
      <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
    </button>
      </form>
    <!-- </div> -->

      </div>


      <!-- Main Body Start -->



      {% include 'Utility/Footer.html' %}
  </div>
  <!-- container ends here-->
  {% include 'Utility/JS_Links.html' %}
  <!--only requried js-->
  <script>
  <!-- collapse -->
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.collapsible').collapsible();
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('select').formSelect();
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.modal').modal();
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    .errorlist{
      font-weight:bold;
    }
  </style>
</body>
</html>
```

here is join.html

```
{% include 'Utility/Title.html' %}
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<meta name="description" content="codeforcoder is a ultimate website for cse students. you can get codes,ppt,ebooks,question papers,placement question and much more.">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,900" rel="stylesheet">

{% include 'Utility/CSS_Links.html' %}
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    {% include 'Utility/NavBar.html' %}



    <!-- Main Body Start -->
     <div class="row">

    <form method="POST" class="col xl6 offset-xl3 l6 offset-l3 m12 s12 center ">

        <h3 class="center" style="font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;">Join CodeforCoder</h3>
            <!-- Modal Trigger -->
  <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger center" href="#modal1">Benefits Of Joining</a>

  <!-- Modal Structure -->
  <div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Modal Header</h4>
      <p>Zindigi Saphal ho jayegi</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
    </div>
  </div>

          <!-- Modal End-->
          {{ form.errors }}
       <div class="row center">
        <div class="input-field col xl12 l12  m12 s12 center">
          {{ form.fullname }}
          <label>Full Name :</label>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row center">
       <div class="input-field  col xl6 l6 m6 s12 center">
          {{ form.registration }}
          <label>Registration No :</label>
       </div>
       <div class="input-field  col xl6 l6 m6 s12 center">
          {{ form.phone }}
          <label>Phone No :</label>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row center">
        <div class="input-field  col xl6 l6 m6 s12 center">
          {{ form.email }}
          <label>Email :</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field  col xl6 l6 m6 s12 center">
           {{ form.confirm_email }}
              <label>Confirm Email :</label>
        </div>

     </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field  col xl6 l6 m6 s12 center">
          {{ form.year }}
          <label>Select Your Year : </label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field  col xl6 l6 m6 s12 center">
              {{ form.role }}
              <label>Select Your Year : </label>
        </div>
    </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col xl12 l12  m12 s12 center">
          {{ form.experience }}
          <label for="Experience">Any Technical Experience*</label>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col xl12 l12 m12 s12 center">
          {{ form.hiringreason }}
          <label for="HiringReason">Why are you working with us?*</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col xl12 l12 m12 s12 center">
        {{ form.botcatcher }}
      </div>
    </div>
      {% csrf_token %}
     <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="submit">Submit
    <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
  </button>
    </form>
  <!-- </div> -->

    </div>


    <!-- Main Body Start -->



    {% include 'Utility/Footer.html' %}
</div>
<!-- container ends here-->
{% include 'Utility/JS_Links.html' %}
<!--only requried js-->
<script>
<!-- collapse -->
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.collapsible').collapsible();
  });
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').formSelect();
  });
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.modal').modal();
  });
</script>
<style>
  .errorlist{
    font-weight:bold;
  }
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: show your template code

Comment: yes, i added template code as contact.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to handle form error condition

try this

```
def contact(request):

   contact_form = formlocal.Contactform()
   context = {'form':contact_form}

   if request.method == 'POST':
      contact_form = formlocal.Contactform(request.POST)

      if contact_form.is_valid():
          contact_form.save(commit=True)
          return redirect('/')
      else:
          context = {'form':contact_form}
          return render(request,'index/contact.html',context=context)
    return render(request,'index/contact.html',context=context)
```

hope it helps

refer [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/)